# How to fix module parse issue when I have the correct webpack configuration?

Tags: wordpress, webpack, sass-loader

I have a WP Site on my local dev environment. I usually use laravel-mix to convert and minify the various JS and SCSS files I have, but I want to move away from that since it's not laravel.

I tested all my configuration on a new WP site and everything seems to build properly with even the SCSS files being converted into CSS and minified.

I uninstalled laravel-mix and installed all the packages I needed to run a proper non-laravel-mix configuration.

Here is a jist of the packages in my package.json

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
  "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
  "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.3.0",
  "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
  "postcss": "^8.3.6",
  "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
  "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
  "sass": "^1.41.1",
  "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
  "webpack": "^5.53.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
},
```

and my webpack.mix.js

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].min.css'
        })],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: { publicPath: "" }
                    },
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                    "postcss-loader"
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].min.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
}
```

And I keep getting an issue with building it as it gives me an error of:

```js
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| // @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
|
> @import 'scss/colors';
| @import 'scss/header';
| @import 'scss/front-page';
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-22
```

As said up top, this is 1-to-1 with my other test site, and that runs smoothly. The only difference is that this site use to use laravel-mix while the other site only had webpack.

I've tried re-install every package; set every package as dependencies instead of devdependecies, and messed around with the webpack.mix.js itself to no avail.

It's been a few days, and I can't find any solutions. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be called

> webpack.config.js

and not

> webpack.mix.js

Very amateur hour from me, but I'll answer this so that if someone has a similar issue, they can see my solution.